# Run java file using 'java filename' command

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal, execution

I want to run java file using 'java filename' command when you're not in the file's directly.

In the terminal we use :

> cd filepath
>
> java filename

but in Eclipse you cannot change the directory using 'cd' so how can I run the file although I can't change the directory

I am using this method to run a command using Java

```
try {
           String line;
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "cd /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src" );
           Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( "java NewFile" );

           BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                   new InputStreamReader(p2.getInputStream()) );
           while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
             System.out.println(line);
           }
           in.close();

     }
     catch (Exception e) {
           // ...
         }
```

Here are several trials

> Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ **cd
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src**
>   Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java NewFile**   5  90  35  45  150  3
>   Reichweite---- nach blase art
>       3  5  35  45  90  150
>
> Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile**
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   .Users.apple.Documents.Documents.workspace.UserTesting.src.NewFile    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>
> Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$ **java
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile.java**
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile/java
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   .Users.apple.Documents.Documents.workspace.UserTesting.src.NewFile.java
>     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)   at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
>   Apples-MacBook-Pro:src apple$
>   Blockquote

Comment: What about `"java /Users/apple/Documents/Documents/workspace/UserTesting/src/NewFile"`?

Comment: @BrianRoach this is question has no correct answers

Answer (score 1):

This will not work.

For one, `cd` is a shell command. And then you create *another* process to run the java command.

You need a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). You can set up the initial directory, environment etc:

```
final File wantedCwd = new File(...);
final ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "thefile");

// Change directory
pb.directory(wantedCwd);
```

You can even change the stdin, stdout, stderr etc of the command.

DO NOT use `Runtime.exec()`. It won't (`exec()`) in many situations.

Comment: Yeah, we tried explaining that to him already the first time he posted this.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't try and search for a previous post...

Comment: @fge that was quite simple explanation thanks a lot